# OWL inferencing question

Tags: semantics, owl, jena

I am using the Jena semantic web framework version 2.6.3.  I have code that creates a model with owl inferencing and then adds the following triples:

```
_:bnode-3 rdf:type            owl:Restriction .

_:bnode-3 owl:onProperty      :offspringOf .

_:bnode-3 owl:someValuesFrom  :Person .

_:bnode-3 rdfs:subClassOf     :Person .
```

`_:bnode-3` is supposed to be a restriction class which, for example, would contain `:joe` if `:bob` is a `:Person` and the following triple were asserted:

```
:joe :offspringOf :bob .
```

Then, since the restriction class is a subclass of Person, `:joe` would also be a person.

And, in fact, this works.  What's confusing to me is that after I assert just the 4 triples at the top of this post, the inferencer creates a blank node which is a Person.  In other words, the following triple is now in the model:

```
_:b0 rdf:type :Person
```

I don't understand why it would do this.  Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
Kent.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the inferencer would do this as I am not an OWL expert - have you tried asking your question on the [jena-users](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-jena-users/) lists?

They will usually answer you pretty promptly and they should know why you get the observed behaviour.

**Note**

I reformatted your question as your code samples were somewhat confusing - please don't write out Triples as `[ex:subject ex:predicate ex:object]` since it looks rather like some syntactic sugar in Turtle/N3/SPARQL which would result in additional Blank Nodes being created beyond just those you intended